# How to make a label blink in asp.net in codebehind

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, label

I would like for a label to blink or flash in my ASP.NET C# codebehind. Can someone please tell me how I can do that? Here is the code that I have tried:

```
label1.Attributes.Add("style", "text-decoration:blink");
```

Using this the label never blinks or flashes. I want to use C# in the codebehind, not JavaScript or HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "blink" setting for `text-decoration` has been depreciated, and browsers are not required to support it.  Internet Explorer and Chrome to not.  Not sure about the others.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is some neat jQuery, i don't know. I have used this javascript in my last ASP.NET project:

```
var g_blinkTime = 400;
var g_blinkCounter = 0;
var g_maxBlinkCount=4;
var g_currentBlinkCount=0;

function blinkElement(elementId){
    var blinkingElement=document.getElementById(elementId);
    if(blinkingElement != null){
        if(g_currentBlinkCount==g_maxBlinkCount){
            g_currentBlinkCount=0;
            blinkingElement.style.visibility = 'visible';
            return;
        }
        if ( (g_blinkCounter % 2) == 0 ){
            blinkingElement.style.visibility = 'visible';
        }else{
            blinkingElement.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }

        if ( g_blinkCounter < 1 ){
            g_blinkCounter++;
        }
        else{
            g_blinkCounter--
        } 

        window.setTimeout('blinkElement(\"' + elementId + '\")', g_blinkTime);
        g_currentBlinkCount++;
    }
}
```

Since that was an `ASP.NET`-Ajax app i've used this to register the script for a label:

```
AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdFilterPanel, typeof(string), "GrdChargeFilterInfoBlink", "blinkElement('" & LblInfo.ClientID & "');", True);
```

But you can also use `ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` instead without Ajax.

**Edit** according to your update: *"I want to use C# in the codebehind, no JavaScript or HTML"*

Blinking controls is done by the client's browser, so the server is not responsible for it. As mentione by [James](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25185063/284240)  you cannot use `text-decoration:blink` since that is not supported by IE and others. So i don't know a different approach than javascript.